# better way of doing a linq query using new

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Is there a better way of doing this - using Entity Framework pulling from a standard SQL server:

I am using a telerik radgrid and putting the field names into the columns ahead of time so it will match up with the data pulled from a linq query like:

```
 var zips = (from z in db.zipcode_lookup select z).ToList();
 zipCodeGrid.DataSource = zips;
```

and it works fine. But I need to combine two fields into one so I now need to do this:

```
var zips = (from z in db.zipcode_lookup select new 
        {
            zip_code = z.zip_code,
            fullName = z.driver_details.first_name + " " + z.driver_details.last_name,
            driver_id = z.driver_id,
            zone = z.zone
        } ).ToList();
```

Which also works fine.  What I am trying to do is to not have to recreate all the fields that are already there (the zip_code, driver_id and zone).

Why can I not do something like:

```
 var zips = (from z in db.zipcode_lookup
              select new
              {
                  z,
                  fullName = z.driver_details.first_name + " " + z.driver_details.last_name
              }                           
      ).ToList();
```

Like I said it works, but I come across this all the time and if there is a better way of doing it I would really appreciate knowing it.

EDIT -

This is a bit shorter (like I said, in this case no big deal, but sometimes with 20 or 30 columns much bigger deal)

```
var zips = (from z in db.zipcode_lookup
                    select new
                    {
                        z.zip_code,
                        z.zone,
                        z.driver_id,
                        fullName = z.driver_details.first_name + " " + z.driver_details.last_name
                    }                           
            ).ToList();
```

I edited someone's answer not realizing it had to be peer reviewed.
for some reason this works with the new class solution presented below:

```
 var zips = (from z in db.zipcode_lookup.ToList()
                    select new ZipData(z)).ToList();
```

Joe

Comment: Sounds like you want a Join or Union.

Comment: There is no better way and yes this is annoying.

Comment: you could use `Automapper` or similar to map two types together.  Not really worth the time though in this scenario

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you don't name them, it takes the original name, (eg, `z.zip_code` automagically gets named `zip_code`) if you'd like to cut down like that. Also, your last example should work, you just need to do `zips.z.zip_code` (name z something else if you like). But as others have said, I don't think there's too much of a way around this.

Comment: You can do something like this by using Expression tree (then you may have to use method syntax). Once creating a helper extension method (for `IQueryable<T>`) such as named `SelectAnonymousWithModification`, you can reuse that helper extension method every time you encounter the same situation. Of course using Expression tree like this will return some non-generic result and you have to cast the result appropriately. The hard part of this approach is creating dynamic anonymous object using `Reflection.Emit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: This is a horrible answer, as it doesn't work with EF. I've added the EF tag to the question to clarify. Please ignore this answer and downvote it at your liesure, as I can't do so myself. [MH]

A possible solution is to declare a small class that holds the data you're returning:

```
public class ZipData
{
    public ZipData (zip_code_lookup z) 
    {
        this.zip_code = z.zip_code;
        this.full_name = string.Format("{0} {1}",
                                       z.driver_details.first_name,
                                       z.driver_details.last_name);
       this.driver_id = z.driver_id;
       this.zone = z.zone;
    }

    public string zip_code { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public int driver_id { get; set; }
    public string zone { get; set; }
}
```

Then, change your Linq expression as follows:

```
var zips = (from z in db.zipcode_lookup 
            select new ZipData(z))
           .ToList();
```

This way, if you need the full name, you have it. If you don't, you can ignore it. Either way, the constructor builds it for you. And you are no longer working with an anonymous type (it doesn't suffer from the constraints of anonymous types).

Comment: clever, but not working quite.  Getting a An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.  On the Linq.  Any thoughts as to a work around?

Comment: Just realized it's an EF query; you're right, that won't work. The query will only accept code that can be converted to SQL. I'm off to downvote my own answer.

Comment: Mike -- my fault, I should have mentioned EF.  Good answer still.  I'm off to edit my question!

Comment: Hold up...your answer works if I change the Linq slightly...see my edit in a sec...

Comment: @MostlyLucid Your (proposed) edit is a question and pretty much turns this post into a forum discussion. The `ToList` trick will solve about any LINQ-to-some-SQL-backend problem, at a cost. I have a feeling you never seriously considered Andres Castro's solution, which I'd prefer.

Comment: @Mike: if you don't like this answer, you can delete it.

Comment: @GertArnold - I will now consider it.  I am just not sure how to do it?  The zipcode object is created by EF, I did not think I could edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say there is a better way of doing it. The thing is, in either case, the C# compiler is going to generate an anonymous type to represent that data. The only way you can get around that is by changing the model. Even if you were writing fewer lines (like only specifying which properties you're adding the one type) it wouldn't really be an improvement in my opinion. There would be more obfuscated behavior and the performance ect would still be the same. I would just recommend going with what you have unless it's little effort to change your model/db.

Answer (score 1):

Just make fullName a getter on the ZipCode object and then you shouldn't need to do the linq statement at all.

```
public string fullName {
   get{
       return driver_details.first_name + " " + driver_details.last_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure how you mean?  The Linq is how I am getting the data from the database -- using Linq to Entities.

Comment: Can we see what the zipcode_lookup entity looks like?

Comment: @MostlyLucid he's suggesting you calculate the value it in the getter but it wouldn't actually work because the data wouldn't exist in that context. To be fair, you didn't specify that it is LINQ to SQL, I just implied that. Would probably work better if you were doing LINQ to Objects.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Wouldn't that data exist if he changed the entity call to Include that property?

Comment: How can I do this?  The zipcode_lookup is a object created by EF.  I do not think I can edit its get, can I?

Comment: @AndresCastro if he changes the entity call to include that property then he has to do a projection/select which will result in the new object being created. I believe that query actually generates a join (it's done implicitly by `z.Relation.PropertyOnRelationTable`), you can't hold the results in C# without there being a new type.

Comment: In code-first: add the property, database-first: add the property in a partial class. Then always remember to `Include()` driver_details. Ready. Just don't use the property in an expression, like `Where(x => x.FullName == ...)`.

Comment: I am not using code first, I am using database first approach.  I am sorry, I am just not following how to do this solution using this method -- am I missing something or is this not viable using database first approach and EF?